# Continuous Approximation for The Kelly Criterion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, gambling

I am trying to follow the derivation of Kelly Criterion, the continuous case. Dr. Thorp shows the basics of the derivation [here](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/cs286r/courses/fall12/papers/Thorpe_KellyCriterion2007.pdf), pg. 22. With initial capital $V_0$, betting fraction $f$, and $X$ is a random variable representing returns where

$$ P(X = m+s) = P(X = m-s) = 0.5$$

The final capital is,

$$ V(f) = V_0 (1 + (1-f)r + fX)  $$

$$ V(f) = V_0 (1 + r + f(X - r))  $$

His eventual goal is to find the $f$ for the maximum $E[\log(V_f)]$, and do this on a continuous scale. So he subdivides the time into $n$ pieces, $m$, $s^2$, and $r$ are replaced by $m/n$, $s^2/n$ and $r/n$ respectively,

$$ P(X_i = m/n + s/\sqrt{n}) = P(X_i = m/n - m/\sqrt{n}) = 0.5$$

$$ V_n(f)/V_0 = \prod _{i=1}^{n} (1 + r + f(X_i - r))  $$

then says take log of both sides, and apply the expectation operator. I did that,

$$ \log V_n(f)/V_0 = \sum _{i=1}^{n} \log (1 + r + f(X_i - r))  $$

$$ E[\log V_n(f)/V_0] = \sum _{i=1}^{n} E[\log (1 + r + fX_i - fr)]  $$

This is where I get stuck, Thorp mentions "we expand the result in a power series", and I've seen a similar trick in a different [book](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwiHv9GLpI_IAhWBbhoKHUxCCnY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.books.mec.biz%2Fdownloads%2FVolatility_Trading%2FNTAxODg3MTQ4&usg=AFQjCNG49u9WfReciDpbLiwMO04JIkJyNQ), pg 137, where the author reaches a statement like $1/1+fg$ after the derivative on a log, and he turned that into $1 - fg + ..$. However I am not able to reach a similar statement.

$$  = n E[\log (1 + r + fX_n - fr)]  $$

Thorp eventually reaches a formula like

$$ g(f) = r + f(m-r) - s^2f^2/2 + O(n^{-1/2})$$

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: He's seem to be using that $\log(1+x) = x - x^2/2 + O(x^3)$, setting $x=r+fX_n-fr$ should result in the final formula (I hope). You're writing "Thorp eventually reaches a formula like", does that mean that there's steps that Thorp has shown that are missing in your question (or did he only come to that formula directly)?

Comment: You crucially forgot to mention that $r$ is also rescaled, into $r/n$. Furthermore $g(f)$ is simply $$g(f)=nE(\log(1+r+f(X-r))).$$ With the scaling by $n$ this becomes $$g_n(f)=nE(\log(1+(r/n)+f(m/n+Us/\sqrt{n}-r/n)))$$ with $U=\pm1$ symmetric Bernoulli, and the expansion $\log(1+u)=u-u^2/2+O(u^3)$ when $u\to0$ yields $$g_n(f)/n=(r/n)+f(m/n+E(U)s/\sqrt{n}-r/n)-f^2s^2E(U^2)/(2n)+O(1/n\sqrt{n}).$$ Can you end this?

Comment: @skyking No Thorp does not show how he reaches the formula unfortunately.

Comment: Actually Thorp does mention that one should expand the logarithm, and this is all one needs to know "how they reach the formula".

Comment: @Did True. Thanks both, I am trying to wrap my head around the answers, and crank through the equations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per @Did's comment, the derivation goes somewhat like this:

$$ P(X = m+s) = P(X = m-s) = 0.5$$

which is compatible with the fact that returns are normal.

With capital $V_0$, allocation $f$, risk-free return $r$

$$ V(f) = V_0 (1 + (1-f)r + fX)  $$

Rearrange

$$ V(f) = V_0 (1 + r + f(X - r))  $$

Divide time into $n$ pieces,

$$ P(X_i = m/n + s/\sqrt{n}) = P(X_i = m/n - m/\sqrt{n}) = 0.5$$

$$ V_n(f)/V_0 = \prod _{i=1}^{n} (1 + r/n + f(X_i - r/n))  $$

We are trying to maximize the log expetation,

$$ E[\log V_n(f)/V_0] = g(f) = n E[\log (1 + (r/n) + f(X_n - (r/n)))]  $$

In order to get rid of the log, we use power series

$$ \log(1+u) = u - \frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{u^3}{3} + .. $$

It's sufficient to use the first two terms.

$$ \log \bigg( 
1 + \frac{r}{n} + f \big( \frac{m}{n} + \frac{Us}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{r}{n} \big) 
\bigg)  $$

Let's look inside the log, the $u$ part

$$ u = \frac{r}{n} + f \big( \frac{m}{n} + \frac{Us}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{r}{n} \big)  $$

.. and what happens to the square of $u$

$$ u^2 = \frac{r^2}{n^2} + f^2(..)^2 + 2 \frac{2}{n}f(...) $$

We are not interested in terms smaller than $O(1/n \sqrt{n})$. So from the statement below for example only $\frac{f^2U^2s^2}{n}$ will "make it". The rest is gone.

$$ \big( \frac{m}{n} + \frac{Us}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{r}{n} \big)^2 
= \frac{m^2}{n^2} + \frac{Usm}{\sqrt{n}n} - ...
$$

We end up with

$$ 
g(f)/n = 
E\big[
\frac{r}{n} + f \big( \frac{m}{n} + \frac{Us}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{r}{n} \big) + 
\frac{f^2U^2s^2}{2n} + 
O(1/n \sqrt{n})
\big]
$$

$$ 
=
\frac{r}{n} + f \big( \frac{m}{n} + \frac{E[U]s}{\sqrt{n}} - \frac{r}{n} \big) + 
\frac{f^2E[U^2]s^2}{2n} + 
O(1/n \sqrt{n})
\big]
$$

Since $E[U] = 0, E[U^2] = 1$

$$ 
=
\frac{r}{n} + f \big( \frac{m}{n} - \frac{r}{n} \big) + 
\frac{f^2s^2}{2n} + 
O(1/n \sqrt{n})
$$

$$ g(f) = r + f(m-r) + f^2s^2/2 + O(1/n \sqrt{n}) $$

As  $n \to \infty$

$$ g(f) = r + f(m-r) + f^2s^2/2 $$

Sources

[The Kelly Criteron](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/cs286r/courses/fall12/papers/Thorpe_KellyCriterion2007.pdf)

[Blog](http://sayilarvekuramlar.blogspot.com/2015/12/zaman-serileri-ve-finans.html)

Comment: Impressive deduction on Kelly Criterion!

It seems like you had mistaken the sign of simplified form of u^2, which stays in the line bellow sentence "We end up with", it shall be a negative one.